# How to connect to "Google Cloud BigQuery" public dataset from "Google Cloud functions"

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-iot

I modified the default *hello_pubsub* (Python3.7) function of "Google Cloud functions" service, for connecting to a dataset table which I have created in the "Google Cloud BigQuery" service. But, after many different approaches, I'm clueless on, how to make this function connect to the dataset I created in BigQuery. I am sure there is an error only with SQLite code of the function. Someone, please help me

My code is:

```py
import sqlite3
import base64

def hello_pubsub(event, context):
    """Triggered from a message on a Cloud Pub/Sub topic.
    Args:
         event (dict): Event payload.
         context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
    """
    connection = sqlite3.connect("<BigQueryDataset>")
    crsr = connection.cursor()
    crsr.execute("SELECT * FROM `iotcoretutorial-xxxxxx.DHT11.DHT11Data` WHERE temperature > 24") 
    ans= crsr.fetchall()    

    pubsub_message = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
    print("Hello "+pubsub_message)
    print(ans)
```

PS: Here *iotcoretutorial-xxxxxx* refers to the project ID. I used *xxxxxx*, to hide my project's identity (Please bear with me for that!)

In short *iotcoretutorial-xxxxxx.DHT11.DHT11Data* is a table created by me on "Google Cloud BigQuery" with temperature and humidity values, which I want to print using *hello_pubsub* function and do some action if temperature value > 24

Comment: Why are you trying to connect to a `bigquery` dataset with the `sqlite3` library? You should probably look at the [BigQuery Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries)

Comment: I'd suggest you change the title. This is not helping you now and it's not going to help anybody else in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [BigQuery Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries). More docs [here too](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/index.html).

```
import base64
from google.cloud import bigquery

def hello_pubsub(event, context):
    """Triggered from a message on a Cloud Pub/Sub topic.
    Args:
         event (dict): Event payload.
         context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
    """
    client = bigquery.Client(project="<your-project>")

    query_str = "SELECT * FROM `iotcoretutorial-xxxxxx.DHT11.DHT11Data` WHERE temperature > 24"

    job = client.query(
        query_str,
        # Location must match that of the dataset(s) referenced in the query.
        location="<your-location>"
    )
    #Wait for job to finish
    job.result()
    #Get results as a dataframe
    #This requires pandas
    #You can do something different with your results here if you want
    ans_df = job.to_dataframe()

    pubsub_message = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
    print("Hello " + pubsub_message)
    print(ans_df)
```

Comment: Just to inform! we need to add following statement `**google-cloud-bigquery = <version>**` ((in my case version is 1.17.0)) in requirements .txt

Comment: Yes, you would need to add that library to your `requirements.txt` if you are using one

Comment: Can you please tell me how to test it? like printing stuff before triggering it. Also my last question is, I want to send a configuration update to an ESP32 (blink it's LED) whenever my temperature goes above 24. How to do this?Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean printing before triggering? Printing where? And I'm afraid I don't know anything about `ESP32` or LEDs.

Comment: Printing the data only with temperature > 24, in Google Cloud Shell! And thanks for helping me the best you can

Comment: Isn't that what those `print` statements do? I'm sorry I haven't used Pub/Sub much